# How to speed up a simple UPDATE of all values in one column, in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

This is taking many hours on a table with over 4.6millon records.

Is there a way to speed this up?

```
UPDATE tableA
SET SKU = CONCAT("X-", tableA.supplier_SKU);
```

There is no index on any column yet.

> EXPLAIN indicates rows=4.6 million, filtered = 100% !

Comment: If this is the real update query, I would question the need for this. Just adding a common prefix to some column looks strange at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an index(indexes) on SKU, dropping it, updating and recreating might help.

Can you lock the table first (ensure no other user is blocking your operation)?

`lock tables tableA write;`

?

Can you create another table, update there and then rename?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html

*note - link above describes how to swap two tables in one statement.

4.6M records doesn't sound like sth that should take hours, unless you can't lock the table because other users keep updating it.

Comment: I don't have any index on any column at the moment.

Comment: no one else is using the database. I just tried it with lock tables. It is still taking very very long. 

EXPLAIN indicates %100 of records are affected for each update. This seems not right unless I am understanding it wrong. All I need is read one column and update another on the same row.

Comment: I just ran the statement with LOCK TABLES and UNLOACK TABLES, it ran a lot faster than before. Thx.

Comment: @Seeker Even if only one or two columns are affected, the whole disk blocks must be read and written. This is, what might cause the long runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableA`.

The slow part is needing to save 4.6 million "old" rows before getting to the "commit".

Do not ever use `LOCK TABLES` with InnoDB.

You *could* break the task into chunks so that it blocks other actions less.  (But the total time will probably be longer.)  See this for 'chunking':  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks